# is their a way to listen to MS teams tab reload

Tags: microsoft-teams

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', leaveEvent)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', leaveEvent)
    }
  }, [data])
```

the initialized microsoftTeams.initialize(); the above code works fine in browser, but not in teams.

Answer (score 0):

You can register a before unload handler to detect/handle when Teams is going to unload your tab with latest Teams SDK. The rules can vary depending on the type of client (mobile versus webapp, versus desktop).

```
microsoftTeams.registerBeforeUnloadHandler()
```

https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-library-js/blob/1478c384cf4131d7755d8edfc9876acc5160dd8e/test/public/publicAPIs.spec.ts#L869

Comment: @Uma - Good to hear that issue is resolved. Thanks for confirming on the same with us.